# the value of category_id is empty

Tags: magento

I'm having an issue with Magento. I'm trying to get the category id of a configurable product but when I call the method getCategoryId, nothing is returned, even if I've attached this configurable product to a category. 
Here is the code I wrote from the Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart class :

```
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();  
    foreach ( $cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
        $prd = $item->getProduct();
        if ( ! $prd->do_not_use_category_id )
            $catId = $prd->getCategoryId();
        else
            $catId = 4;
        break;
    }
```

Besides, there is a boolean named "do_not_use_category_id" that is true for these products.
How can I get the category id from this product ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the top of my head - since I don't have a Magento environment around right now - shouldn't it be:

```
$prd->getCategoryIds(); //Note the "s" after "Id".
```

A product can be part of multiple categories, so it would make sense. Let me know if this worked or not.